# In Django, how do you make a model refer to itself?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Assume we have class `Employee`. I want to have a field which references a different instance of the same class.

How to write this? How about the following code?

```
ref_employee= models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

> To create a recursive relationship --
>   an object that has a many-to-one
>   relationship with itself -- use
>   `models.ForeignKey('self')`.

So you have it right. It's usually faster to determine if code will do what you want by running it :)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Also, just because something appears to work doesn't mean that it's a good idea to do it that way.  Better to find out the correct way and learn from other people's experience and mistakes.

Comment: @dsjoerg, completely agreed ;)

Comment: Just an explanation. Since Django 2.0 you need to pass the "on_delete" property to the ForeignKey class. If you don't, you'll have that error: "TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'". Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete to understand how option you have to use in your case.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you can even exclude the app name which would look like:

```
ref_employee= models.ForeignKey('Employee',null=True,blank=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can reference other models by name (using a string, including
package), instead of by the class directly:

So, if your `Employee` class is in the `hr` app:

```
class Employee(models.model):
   other_employee = models.ForeignKey('hr.models.Employee', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I found that the reference needed to leave out the 'models' part of the model reference (ie. `models.ForeignKey('hr.Employee', null=True, blank=True)` )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct but consider writing `'null=True'` because if you don't mention that, your database recursively creates a joint table.

Comment: ```your database recursively create a joint table``` what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

A constraint forcing `id` and `ref_employee_id` to have separate values is outside the scope of Django's ORM. You will need to add said constraint at the database level, via SQL in syncdb or manually.