# Python / Django: Make a lookup / database query inside a model class

Tags: python, django, lookup

What is the right way to lookup a table and use its last value as a value in a new model instance? Something like this:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    obj = MyClass.objects.latest('id')
    my_field = models.IntegerField(default=(obj+1))
```

I need a db column, which keeps track of the primary_key, but is independent of it and can also be modified. Also I need to use its value as default when creating new instances of the Model.

Comment: Why would you do this? Isn't that what the `id` already does?

Comment: When you said "a new model class", did you mean a new instance of the same model? If you're trying to automatically increment the id, as Roseman said you don't have to implement it yourself.

Comment: Because it is not possible to use id directly, something like default=id doesn't work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4910905/1324033

Comment: You can't just simply add `1` to model instance `obj` as you mentioned in your question.
Could you please be more specific in what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Can I make a db query and use the value as `default=value` in my model?

Answer (score 0):

you can use custom constructor as described in the docs: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/

you will need to define the obj field either as integer(to store the id of the previous record) or as a foreign key(if you want to reference the previous db record). In the second case you will need to  pass the name of the model to the ForeignKeyField constructor as string('MyClass') and not directly(MyClass).