# How can I save a model instance that references itself in django?

Tags: python, django, model

I have the following code:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent')
```

In some cases, I would like the model instance to be its own parent. This may be done by saving the new instance and then assigning the parent field, but I need this to be done before saving, since there is some code that depends on post_save signal and that needs the model's parent info.

Comment: As far as I know, you can not do that, perhaps you can make the field `null=True`, and use `None`, such that the `post_save` model knows this. I also think that even if it *was* possible, the `post_save` would not see the id for the `parent`, since it will only retrieve the primary key and set that to the "in-mempory" object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Django, how do you make a model refer to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910905/in-django-how-do-you-make-a-model-refer-to-itself)

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili: but that part is fixed, at the model/class level, it is indeed referencing the model. The question is, how do you reference it at *object* level, and immediately after construction.